# Windows App Certification Kit Warning

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, app-certification-kit

I have an app that developed for Windows 7 & 8. Developed in VS2010 using C++/CLI. When tried to certify with Windows App Certification Kit, it shows a warning.

```
Binary analyzer
Warning: The binary analyzer test detected the following errors:
File C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\msvcr100.dll has failed the ExecutableImportsCheck check.
File C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\msvcp100.dll has failed the ExecutableImportsCheck check.
Impact if not fixed: If the app doesn’t use the available Windows protections, it can increase the vulnerability of the customer's computer to malware.
How to fix: Apply the SAFESEH, DYNAMICBASE, and NXCOMPAT options when you link the app.
```

How can I avoid this warning from my app.

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense to use WACK on your project.  It was made to verify WinRT apps, the kind that are published through the Store and run on Windows 8.x or Windows Phone.  They need to be safe to run in a very restricted sandbox that makes a very small subset of the winapi available.  Limited for security, deployment and power-consumption reasons, what WACK verifies.  A desktop DLL like msvcr100.dll cannot meet them.  Such apps are built with another CRT, vccorlibxxx.dll

You cannot build such an app with VS2010, VS2012 or higher required.  Nor can it run on Win7.  You simply need to stop using the tool.

---

Update: it does appear that WACK was updated in the 8.1 SDK to also verify Windows Logo requirements for desktop apps.  This is obscure.  Judging from the command help that's displayed when I run appcert.exe /? in an elevated command prompt, you must first create an installer for your app.  Then you can run appcert with the `-apptype desktop` and the `-setuppath yourinstaller.exe` to have it perform the validation.  Some additional command line options appear to matter, like `-appusage`.  I don't know what they mean.

Do keep in mind that this is only useful if you need the Windows Logo certification.  There ought to be additional information in the logo program documentation about this.  Consider contacting Microsoft if you have Windows Logo program questions.

Comment: But here 
http://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/app-certification-kit
it says that WACK (from version 3.3)Supports, Desktop apps for Win 8, 8.1 and Windows 7

Comment: Okay, that's obscure.  Judging from the appcert.exe command help (type appcert.exe /? in an elevated command prompt), you'll first need to create an installer for your program.  Then you must run appcert.exe with the -apptype desktop and -setuppath yourinstaller.exe options.  Some more obscure options seem to matter, like -appusage, not sure what they mean.  Never heard of anybody doing this, good luck with it :)

Comment: @HansPassant - Perhaps due to the buzz about supporting non-metro apps in the Windows Store next year.  http://www.dailytech.com/Microsoft+to+Allow+NonMetro+Apps+Into+the+Windows+Store+Next+Year/article36674.htm